# Differences between useImperativeHandle and generic object assignment

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm in the process of building out a UI library and had a `TagPicker` component which allows users to select tags to filter their search by.

I've contemplated whether it's better to manage the component's state from it's parent or from within the component itself and came across a question I hadn't encountered before and couldn't seem to find much about online.

Essentially, if I were to manage the state from within the component, i'd have something roughly like this:

```
import React, { useState, type HTMLAttributes } from 'react'

type Props = HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>

const TagPicker = React.forwardRef<HTMLDivElement, Props>(({tags, ...rest}, ref) => {
    // State
    const [selectedTags, setSelectedTags] = useState<SelectedTagsState>(initialState)

    return (
      <div ref={ref} {...rest} >
        {tags?.map(tag => (
          <Tag
            key={tag.id}
            title={tag.title}
            isActive={selectedTags.includes(tag)}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    )
})
```

Then say I wanted access to `selectedTags` and `setSelectedTags` from outside the `TagPicker` component (in it's parent for example).

One suggestion may be to use `useImperativeHandle` like so:

```
import React, { useState, type HTMLAttributes } from 'react'

type Props = HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>

const TagPicker = React.forwardRef<HTMLDivElement, Props>(({tags, ...rest}, ref) => {
    // State
    const [selectedTags, setSelectedTags] = useState<SelectedTagsState>(initialState)

    useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
      getSelectedTags: () => selectedTags,
      setSelectedTags   
     })

    return (
      <div ref={ref} {...rest} >
        {tags?.map(tag => (
          <Tag
            key={tag.id}
            title={tag.title}
            isActive={selectedTags.includes(tag)}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    )
})
```

However, I wonder whether there are any pros or cons (or whether it's simply considered somewhat of an anti-pattern) to do something like this:

```
import React, { useState, type HTMLAttributes } from 'react'

type Props = HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>

const TagPicker = React.forwardRef<HTMLDivElement, Props>(({tags, ...rest}, ref) => {
    // State
    const [selectedTags, setSelectedTags] = useState<SelectedTagsState>(initialState)

    useEffect(() => {
      if (ref.current) {
        ref.current.selectedTags = selectedTags
        ref.current.setSelectedTags = setSelectedTags
      }
    }, [ref, selectedTags, setSelectedTags])

    return (
      <div ref={ref} {...rest} >
        {tags?.map(tag => (
          <Tag
            key={tag.id}
            title={tag.title}
            isActive={selectedTags.includes(tag)}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    )
})
```

Any thoughts or insight would be welcome. They both seem to yield the same result when logged to the console, however the second option does allow you to keep all the DOM nodes existing attributes.

Comment: From first look its the same, you just implementing useImperativeHandle, the only problem that you can have edge cases/bugs that you are not aware of. For example, Im pretty sure [ref] won't trigger the useEffect, check if changing ref (without unmounting) triggers your callback